# How to upload Java archive (.WAR) to Windows Server on Plesk?

Tags: java, plesk, windows-server, war

I am able to create a `.WAR` archive of my Java project from Eclipse. This is what I tried:

`Plesk Home Page -> Domains -> example.com -> Java Applications -> Install Java Application`

But when I click The *Install Java Application* button it shows this warning:

[image: Error image]

Please help me, anything will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that while Tomcat feature is available for your subscription, the current limit for Java application is 'zero'. Contact your server provider to sort it out.
If you are a server owner, login into Plesk and check the following:

1. Plesk license allows creating resources of this type (**Tools & Settings > License Management**).
2. Subcription service plan has enough resources (**Subscriptions > example.com > Service plan**).
3. If the subscription is locked check the customized resources (**Subscriptions > example.com > Customize**).

If the subscription assigned to the customer created by reseller, then verify reseller's resources availability:

1. Reseller' service plan has not enough resources (**Service Plans > Reseller Plans**).
2. If the reseller' subscription is locked check the customized resources (**Resellers > My reseller > Customize**).
   Locked state means locked for syncing, indicates that a subscription is excluded from syncing with the associated plans.

A subscription gets locked parameters of the subscription are changed without changing the associated service plan. Such locking secures the customization so that they are not overwritten the next time, when the plan parameters are changed and all its subscriptions are synced.

Unsynced state indicates that some services or resources offered with the associated plans cannot actually be provided with the subscription.